# smb mount via fstab mount error 5

Tags: mount, password, samba, fstab

Something weird happened in the last weeks don't know why, before it worked perfectly so here's my problem:

I am mounting my NAS via fstab and a script which looks like this, taken from fstab:

```
//192.168.178.26/photo      /home/user/photo    cifs    users,noauto,port=139,user=user,password=password 0 0
```

and from the script (or xterm)

```
mount /home/user/photo
```

This worked very well the for a long time but now I'm receiving the following error:

```
mount error(5): Input/output error Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

But the mount via xterm command

```
mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=password //192.168.178.26/photo /home/user/photo
```

works....
any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

When you mount it via `mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=password //192.168.178.26/photo /home/user/photo` the open /etc/mtab and use the line from there and put it into fstab.

Something like:

`sudo cat /etc/mtab | grep '/home/user/photo' >> /etc/fstab`

Comment: many thanks for the answer, it didn't really solve my problem but gave me an idea.. removing the port=139 entry solved it..